# Testing Library APIS without Using a GUI

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, android-debug, android-developer-api

Is there any way to test the available APIS from a aar Android Library without creating a GUI?
I want to create a GUI less activity using the aar library and run it and send commands to it using the adb commands from the PC and invoke the Android APIS and test it.

please assist.